# split a long string at the closest comma after N characters and loop each string

Tags: regex, linux, string, shell, unix

**Input**

```
    stringType1= ('34343,43434, 34343, 434343,
234243,343433,53434,4343,4343
434344,434343,434343,43434,4343
etc...till approx 50K character length')

stringType2= ('34343','43434', '34343', '434343',
'234243','343433','53434','4343','4343'
)
etc...till approx 50K character length'
# Note the new line \n after group of 4-5 strings         
  and some have space before  them and some don't
```

Split the string in into smaller strings .Each string should not be more than 10K characters and 
Split at the closest comma ( before or after any comma) and should be serially numbered

**Output**

```
From 
stringType1 
StTy1_1=('34343,43434,34343,434343'...) #stop at 10k characters
StTy1_2=('234243,343433,53434,4343,4343'...) #stop at 10k characters


 # keep making bundles of 10K character strings 
 # Splitting stringType1  at the closest comma after 10k characters.
 # Remove all space character and single quotes 
 # except the ones at the ends of  each string 
    StTy2_1=('34343,43434,34343,434343'...) #stop at 10k characters
    StTy2_2=('234243,343433,53434,4343,4343'...) #stop at 10k characters
    Then each 10K string takes an eacho statement around it 
   echo "sel function ('34343,43434,34343,434343'...) as D1" >> file 
   echo "sel function ('234243,343433,53434,4343,4343'...) as D2" >> file
```

**What I did**
Removed all newline , spaces and single quotes

```
 stringType1_op= ('34343,43434, 34343,434343,234243,343433,53434,4343,4343,434344,434343,434343,43434,4343
etc...till approx 50K character length')
```

**What I need**

- Split stringType1 after 10k , at the closest comma
- Counter : after each string 10K string is created have a counter mech that will do this

```
     echo "sel function ('34343,43434,34343,434343'...) as D1" >> file
```

Comment: Can you pl explain the sed logic. I might be able to use it , tweaked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution might be an awk script. With awk you can avoid a while loop.
A while loop becomes slow when you need to call external utilities, which I avoid here.
I first call some utilities to get each number on a newline:

```
sed -n '/stringType/ p' input | tr " ,'" "\n" | tr -s "\n"
```

I will process this with a loop:

```
startline=1
endline=0
dimnumber=0
sed -n '/stringType/ p' input | tr " ,'" "\n" | tr -s "\n"  | while read -r line; do
   if [[ "${startline}" = "1" ]]; then
      totallen=0
      printf "%s" "echo sel function ('"
      startline=0
      (( dimnumber++))
      continue
   fi
   if [[ "${line}" =~ ^[0-9] ]]; then
       if [[ "$totallen" = "0" ]]; then
          printf "%s" "${line}"
       else
          printf "%s" ",${line}"
       fi
       (( totallen += ${#line} ))
   fi
   if [[ ${totallen} -gt 10 ]]; then
      endline=1
   fi
   if [[ "${line}" = *\)* ]]; then
      endline=1
   fi
   if [[ "${endline}" = "1" ]]; then
      printf "%s%s\n" "') as Dim" "${dimnumber}"
      endline=0
      startline=1
   fi
done
```